# RGB to Xterm Color Converter

Tags: code-golf, color

256-color Xterm-compatible terminals add 240 colors on top of the usual 16 system colors. Colors 16-231 use 6 levels (0, 95, 135, 175, 215, 255) of red, green, and blue, ordered lexicographically. Colors 232-255 are simply 24 levels of gray (8...238 by 10s). To get a better idea of what I'm talking about, see [this table](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/).

## The Challenge

Your goal is to make a program or function that takes, as input, rgb values, and outputs the number corresponding with the closest Xterm color to that rgb value. **Since the 16 system colors (colors 0-15) are often customizable, you will be excluding them from this conversion.**

To better define what the "closest" color is, use the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) along red, green, and blue components. For example, `rgb(10, 180, 90)` is 20 units away from `rgb(0, 175, 95)` (color 35) because `abs(10 - 0) + abs(180 - 175) + abs(90 - 95) == 20`. If the input color is equally between two or more Xterm colors, output the Xterm color with the highest index.

## Examples

```
 R   G   B     Xterm
  0   0   0 ==> 16
 95 135   0 ==> 64
255 255 255 ==> 231
238 238 238 ==> 255

 90 133 140 ==> 66
218 215 216 ==> 188
175 177 178 ==> 249

175   0 155 ==> 127
 75  75  75 ==> 239
 23  23  23 ==> 234
115 155 235 ==> 111
```

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden
- Your program or function is allowed to take rgb values in any reasonable format, including:

  - Separate arguments for red, green, and blue
  - A list, tuple, dictionary, or similar
  - Delimiter-separated string or stdin
  - Hex colors (e.g. `#ff8000`)
- You may assume that all r, g, and b, values will be integers between 0 and 255.
- Since the 16 system colors are to be excluded from the mapping, all outputs should be in the range 16...255.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 132 bytes

```hs
v=0:[95,135..255]
f c=snd$maximum[(-sum(abs<$>zipWith(-)c x),i)|(i,x)<-zip[16..]$[[r,g,b]|r<-v,g<-v,b<-v]++[[g,g,g]|g<-[8,18..238]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDLboMwEEX3@YopYmGEQTGER6rQL2hXrdSFZVU8HEAFgjCkqMq/0zHNhtZ4LOQDx9dTpepTNs2yXJP9Iz8GlPmB63pBIHZnyBPVFWabznU7tZw4ampJmqmT@fRd9@/1WBHHymG2aG3dSE1n6@Qg4Cx0XWFyPtCSZuI2nJwrLfWS4SJsm/MSSSluuMljymI80I@FEEub1h0kUFx2gKORI4xSjUBydCf1GXSkZIaxkh0McpyGjlggGyVBDsNlMFV1@YLctg3At6kpIJNg2Pa6Pa/ONu1fPn6tnPA9xUdQFlp0pXqQexc0CA8bgG2h9xLU89kW@jG9l9BfbJV7VPqUHbR0e5rH8B@GUhZikjjeQBZhlijC0tLD8R9Erw7DvGiDkKxTxzz@iUnXqcn2dgxDMH07XwsZs8QK@2l8HYfnDow37JqCPlVKFg/G8gM)

Takes input as a list of integers `[red, green, blue]`.

Fairly straightforward implementation. First I build a list of the Xterm colors we're using with two list comprehensions concatenated together. The first of which handles colors 16-231 by triple iterating over `v` which contains the values those colors use. The second one just iterates over the grey values and puts them in all three slots. Then I index it with zip (starting at 16) and make a pair with the manhattan distance (negated) and that index and take the maximum. I used maximum because we're tie-breaking on the largest index and this way saves me one extra `-`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>280</s> <s>180</s> <s>166</s> <s>164</s> 155 bytes

```ruby
->c{d=0,95,135,175,215,255
a=(0..239).map{|n|n<216?[d[n/36],d[(n%36)/6],d[n%6]]:[n*10-2152]*3}.map{|t|t.zip(c).map{|a,b|(a-b).abs}.sum}
a.rindex(a.min)+16}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHRbuMgEHz3V6xcWbJzhHpN4iTVuf2Fe0foRGyis9RQKxCpvTrfngMMvT4wXpjdmd315Xr8uJ@6@/q5/xy6mhy2BJk7uy1p0J3tNpNdWVPasENFz3L6nPWsfzbYvvCB60fWCjLwUhesrR5DrItWiCeuV1ivnUQjVuy2FNrZ0r/jVPZRSJLjXMr1saLyaG7UXM@3TNLLqAf1Xkp6HnX1A9vb3Spjf/fSKAMd8AyAc4CaQALhEJ33wrgJwI@QmHYTGTcLgQSOaRgmhu39dQER@ahWezXmYLOoJZ8GfTp6Ne8NuN9Hxu8OcLfzENQ2h@9M6BpDB9jskk9gIoTeUo0L3WOEwKR50JtjmIcFNUSRiSz7vy6qZP8HhjeYRz1drSGg3ifVWzXMTuGizPXVupWe@EK7WoAH@HVR1n6Al4k5xr37BMh5wQYCCQR0z/4LZWGqHIrwcwBW0S1cFoXvMXTdVx/wAvkkjcnhCfKTHF9zlygypYf7Pw)

A lambda taking the input color as an array of integers.

I had more trouble generating the Xterm colors than I expected! I'm prepared to be outgolfed <s>embarrassingly</s> modestly in that area. I used base conversion as a kind of compression, <s>but the only way I know to do so in Ruby is through `Integer#to_s`</s> which is a little bit awkward.

-100 bytes: Read the problem more carefully, and ignore the 16 system colors ^_^;

-14 bytes: Use hand base conversion instead of `.to_s(6)`

-2 bytes: Skip square brackets when declaring array

-9 bytes: Create list of Xterm colors with only one `map`; this also saves a plus sign and a pair of parens.

```ruby
->c{
  d=0,95,135,175,215,255                 # d is the set of possible RGB values
  a=(0..239).map{|n|                     # Create the array of Xterm triplets
    n<216 ? [d[n/36],d[(n%36)/6],d[n%6]] # Convert x from base 6 to base d, or
          : [n*10-2152]*3                #   create a uniform triplet
  }.map{|t|
    t.zip(c).map{|a,b|(a-b).abs}.sum     # Map from triplets to Manhattan distance
  }
  a.rindex(a.min) +                      # Find the last index of the lowest distance
  16                                     # Offset for the exluded system colors
}
```

Comment: BTW, You don't need to map to the 16 system colors. Maybe I should make that clearer in the description.

Comment: Ooh, that will help me quite a bit! I definitely missed that in the original question wording.

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>299</s> <s>290</s> <s>267</s> 265 bytes

```kotlin
(16..255).associate{it to if(it<232)(it-16).let{i->listOf(0,95,135,175,215,255).let{l->listOf(l[i/36],l[(i/6)%6],l[i%6])}}else(8..238 step 10).toList()[it-232].let{listOf(it,it,it)}}.minBy{(k,v)->(it.zip(v).map{(a,b)->kotlin.math.abs(a-b)}.sum()*256)+(256-k)}!!.key
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
(16..255).associate {
    it to if (it < 232) (it - 16).let { i ->
            listOf(0, 95, 135, 175, 215, 255).let { l ->
                listOf(
                        l[i / 36],
                        l[(i / 6) % 6],
                        l[i % 6])
            }
        } else (8..238 step 10).toList()[it - 232].let { listOf(it, it, it) }
}.minBy { (k, v) ->
    (it.zip(v).map { (a, b) -> kotlin.math.abs(a - b) }.sum() * 256) + (256 - k)
}!!.key
```

### Test

```kotlin
data class Test(val r: Int, val g: Int, val b: Int, val out: Int)

val test = listOf(
        Test(0, 0, 0, 16),
        Test(95, 135, 0, 64),
        Test(255, 255, 255, 231),
        Test(238, 238, 238, 255),

        Test(90, 133, 140, 66),
        Test(218, 215, 216, 188),
        Test(175, 177, 178, 249),

        Test(175, 0, 155, 127),
        Test(75, 75, 75, 239),
        Test(23, 23, 23, 234),
        Test(115, 155, 235, 111)
)
fun z(it:List<Int>): Int =
(16..255).associate{it to if(it<232)(it-16).let{i->listOf(0,95,135,175,215,255).let{l->listOf(l[i/36],l[(i/6)%6],l[i%6])}}else(8..238 step 10).toList()[it-232].let{listOf(it,it,it)}}.minBy{(k,v)->(it.zip(v).map{(a,b)->kotlin.math.abs(a-b)}.sum()*256)+(256-k)}!!.key

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (i in test) {
        val r = z(listOf(i.r, i.g, i.b))
        println("$i ${i.out} ==> $r")
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##ZVNRj9owDH7vr_CdmJTc2hxpaSkIKm1vkybtYXtD95DeFRa1tKgNSFD1t_HAH5udHojRKHEc-4vt2E5emUKXl7PzoYyC90I1DfzJGsMOqoB6Dj9K4wLxmzs-veOrvbEn7jh0NHgXllDoxvxaMwc-hzU5dqGfMuLu_6pZiNIgtNpo8qj1Q9TckUAOEEFM8hsJQ0Q8uCDHQYBkQk4GIfiSLkqyLyNExfEjQk4pyumUCGEns4ETCyFHFKf0p48mSH1dfjAbPoPE1zXIg6ToZJ8C4qTkDnfW-xJOTJv5T0z6AkuRcFsRWF7OTEZCUDYEFrZ618pkrTZgKtBrvLLwA5_j7mFFRJGZVnvJZ-nGLtaESkJPorRYK4QpbphipV-D6M0tVky_RvyLZTVuvOuyoslYjM6DGBqT7UCOuTAVxcj4Cl2i67feXm9MG9dOvCu2uvx-bFnuHriXoEac9I4duNiqXcuUm6I0t42LEvNXqLRhykt5J5r9lvEXP4z4V-yayMt59_Qk8uyIHU552ipdMlVvmjl8q2t1XPw2tS43CYfWpnpd1cA06NI28lVKw_4H7OwTu8Yrahe02BBJOb8Bd2jQFCV7HmkYtVrgB-lguUxgVD_3qM7pLud_)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¬ÿ▒ú╘Σt∙Æ9φ☻ùí&BQq═IÜH∩Å╧♥f⌠óH]╨⌡≤@■Q‼Hr¼
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C2%AC%C3%BF%E2%96%92%C3%BA%E2%95%98%CE%A3t%E2%88%99%C3%869%CF%86%E2%98%BB%C3%B9%C3%AD%26BQq%E2%95%90I%C3%9CH%E2%88%A9%C3%85%E2%95%A7%E2%99%A5f%E2%8C%A0%C3%B3H%5D%E2%95%A8%E2%8C%A1%E2%89%A4%40%E2%96%A0Q%E2%80%BCHr%C2%BC&i=%5B0%2C0%2C0%5D%0A%5B95%2C135%2C0%5D%0A%5B255%2C255%2C255%5D%0A%5B238%2C238%2C238%5D%0A%5B90%2C133%2C140%5D%0A%5B218%2C215%2C216%5D%0A%5B175%2C177%2C178%5D%0A%5B175%2C0%2C155%5D%0A%5B75%2C75%2C75%5D%0A%5B23%2C23%2C23%5D%0A%5B115%2C155%2C235%5D&a=1&m=2)

ASCII version of 50 bytes:

```
"4GOW_g"{52-5*m3|^24{A*vv]3*m+{;\{E:-m|+mc|m|IH16+
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <del>202 192 157 150 (141 bugged) 138</del> 134 bytes

```
l,m,t,i;a(c,x){x=abs(c-=i>215?i*10-2152:x*40+!!x*55);}f(r,g,b){for(i=l=240;i--;t=a(r,i/36)+a(g,i/6%6)+a(b,i%6),t<l?l=t,m=i:1);i=m+16;}
```

Thanks @ceilingcat

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBboMwEETvfIWTKpINRmFtDCSukx/pBUhAloBUKQekKP11ajuksXrpZVjxmJll67it63nuaE9HqmWJazqR26TK6gvXsdIHBuJYRFjHDDISQrKfwjSJVqspFILIe4OvtKUVuTWXK9aqUyxN5LeOYzmq0jC95RmJStyaKdu4saLaDHR8746dGmmv9B6I1KqPIJP3@e10bvRwRtO4RH9e9TA2eL05fQxr@iwkMuhLPWByC8yXCCUUPYVItN0ipQ4IMgd3giLg4g/MUguZMO@f8oKMw7@5jBfGtYhnFeLRmthWbiT1Wx9WsC6wreasr9yisBRyu3CeW/GD090vdTuBvzGw3NU6uoj/P85rngYs4lN3C7ALgbsF95MBgvv8Aw)

Comment: The problem isn't defined by the tests (which are clearly labeled as examples), so please get a new test added instead.

Comment: @TonHospel I fixed the bug now and cut down -3 bytes, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 266 bytes

```
@set/ax=15,m=999
@set s=for %%b in (0 95 135 175 215 255)do @
@%s:b=r%%s:b=g%%s%call:c %* %%r %%g %%b
@for /l %%g in (8,10,238)do @call:c %* %%g %%g %%g
@echo %n%
:c
@set/ax+=1,r=%4-%1,g=%5-%2,b=%6-%3
@set/ad=%r:-=%+%g:-=%+%b:-=%
@if %d% leq %m% set/an=x,m=d
```